# What is Max and average summary mean?

Tags: rowing-machine

After finishing a "challenge" the matrix rower shows you a Max and average summary:
[image]

What is the difference? I don't get what the context is here. Is average my average over the the challenge? Is Max the total calories I burned for the challenge?

Edit: just want to add im most curious about the value of calories under MAX- what is that? What is the diff between calories under average and max summary?

Answer (score 3):

The numbers that are changing between the two displays - pace, power, and stroke rate - are all instantaneous measurements, meaning that they normally would represent a single point in time during your workout. They can be applied to your whole workout only by averaging them over the duration of the workout.

So you had an average pace of 2:14/500m over your workout, and the maximum speed that you hit was a pace of 1:57/500m. Your average power was 142 watt, and the power you were putting out during your most powerful stroke was 216 watt. Your average stroke rate was 32 strokes per minute, but at the fastest point in the workout you were pulling at 41 strokes per minute.

You burned an estimated 1094 kcal during the workout, but I have no idea what the 2714 value in place of this on the max screen is.

These numbers suggest that you were working at quite a consistent intensity. Whereas if you had been doing an interval training workout, where you alternate periods of unsustainably high intensity exertion with periods of rest, then you would expect to see much bigger differences between the average and max values.

Comment: "I have no idea what the 2714 value in place of this on the max screen is" thats the main thing i want to know. I thought the calorie count under max was for the whole workout time? but then what is average? Im going to edit my question to make it clear this is what Im most curious about

Comment: I *believe* the 2714 value is the amount of calories you'd burn in an hour if you kept that max intensity up for the entire hour.  The 1094 number is the average calories you'd burn per hour given the average intensity for the entire session.

Comment: @DeeV I considered that, however 2714 is 2.5x the 1094 kcal burned during the whole workout, whereas the max power is only 1.5x the average power, the max stroke rate is only 1.3x the average stroke rate, and the max pace is only 1.15x faster than the average pace. So I don't think that checks out. The fact that the max screen doesn't display "cal" for this number is also suspicious. Might need to consult the user manual to get an answer for this.

Comment: @red888 I found the user manual for this rower, but it didn't have any information on what that 2714 number was. I'd recommend that you just ignore it, as it's really unlikely to be anything valuable, and for the purposes of assessing how much fitter you're getting from session to session, the averages screen is much more useful info.

Comment: i didnt see it in the manual either! well what are my total calories then? under average?

Comment: Yes, the cal value on the average screen is how many total calories you burned over the workout.